# Not able to find Existing Organization Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

We are planning to move to SES production and was denied this request as support is saying your existing account is on pause. Use that account. We arent able to find that account. How can we find it.
Is there a way to find all existing accounts with your domain in aws(assuming they were made as new account).

AWS support is not sharing that account name